# need solution for IE browser timeout

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, jsf, timeout

The scenario is like
There is a screen, user submits a form and he has to wait for 15mins for response(a lot of data processing at serverside) but IE throws broser timeout in 5mins

I can't use asynchronus form submission
I can't modify any registry values at user machine
I can't do ajax polling(dummy call)

Is there any way that i can avoid this problem?

Or will the below code snippet avoid my problem

Take a html UI component and update the execution time using javascript for every sec...!

Any solution is appriciated

Comment: Asked this question from mobile, hard to type so explained the way to write the code

Comment: Have you considered using a socket library to ping the client when the processing is done?

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS - to be fair, several of his questions have had zero answers, so he can't be expected to have accepted and answer on those.

Comment: @JainiNaveen - you mentioned a code snippet in the question... any chance we can see that so we can understand the problem a bit better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serverside should be doing some sort of batch processing and the client should poll the server until it is done. You should not except one connection to stay open for a long time.